# Yii2 asset compression using closure compiler and yuicompresser

Tags: yii2, assets, yui, google-closure-compiler

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html

i generate **assets.php** in the root of the application using this command **yii asset/template assets.php**

assets.php

```
            <?php
            /**
             * Configuration file for the "yii asset" console command.
             */

            // In the console environment, some path aliases may not exist. Please define these:
            // Yii::setAlias('@webroot', __DIR__ . '/../web');
            // Yii::setAlias('@web', '/');

            return [
                // Adjust command/callback for JavaScript files compressing:
                'jsCompressor' => 'java -jar compiler.jar --js {from} --js_output_file {to}',
                // Adjust command/callback for CSS files compressing:
                'cssCompressor' => 'java -jar yuicompressor.jar --type css {from} -o {to}',
                // The list of asset bundles to compress:
                'bundles' => [
                    // 'app\assets\AppAsset',
                    // 'yii\web\YiiAsset',
                    // 'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
                ],
                // Asset bundle for compression output:
                'targets' => [
                    'all' => [
                        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetBundle',
                        'basePath' => 'C:/wamp/www/flywings/frontend/web/assets',
                        'baseUrl' => '/flywings/frontend/web/assets',
                        'js' => 'js/all-{hash}.js',
                        'css' => 'css/all-{hash}.css',
                    ],
                ],
                // Asset manager configuration:
                'assetManager' => [
                    //'basePath' => '@webroot/assets',
                    //'baseUrl' => '@web/assets',
                ],
            ];
```

and i installed closure compiler and yuicompresser in my pc at the following path **C:\closure-compiler** and **C:\YUI\yuicompressor\build**

and i dont know how to proceed to next step.in the assets.php whats the {from} {to} and how to add the bundles there(manually ?).I am using the advanced application.

Comment: figured it out yet? Where do i call the `assets.php` file?